# App not loading content on WiFi

Tags: applications, wi-fi, mobile-data, android-one

I have a problem with an app not loading content on WiFi. If I switch to mobile data it works normally. I disabled battery optimization for it, set the WiFi network to be treated as unmetered but with no success. It works whenever it wants. I didn't disable any important system services or apps (chrome, wellbeing, files go, google, lens, moto help, moto notifications). I have a Motorola One. My last phone, LG G6 had no trouble with it, I am using the same router/network. It's misbehaving on both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz.

Comment: Does the content loading while the app is in background or does the problem occur when you use the app and it is in foreground?

Comment: Foreground, there isn't supposed to be background activity.

Comment: May be this is an incompatibility of the App because of a newer Android version? The LG G6 had Android 9 and the new phone Android 10? The only chance you have is checking `adb logcat` for errors to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Yeah I think it's something to do with the Android. I've just updated to Android 10 and it's working now only that it's freezing now instead of not loading pictures.

Comment: Have you checked the Google PlayStore comments? Usually if an app does not work on Android 9+ you will find that info there. Additionally you can check `adb logcat  if it displays error for the app. Third as it is a problem of a specific app you can name the app (including PlayStore/download link). May be someone knows a workaround for that specific app.

Comment: You're right. The app hasn't been updated in 2 years, at least that's what it shows on my Android 10 play store. I remember updating it on my LG G6. Could it be that it received updates only for the G6, ie Android 9? I'm not sure how app development works.

Comment: Different app versions for different devices are possible in PlayStore. Check the app detail page and scroll down to the `Current Version` section. If there is no concrete version named but `Varies with device` then this app has different versions for different devices (but you don't know what device gets which version it may be just a split because of ARMv7 ARMv8 and x86 cpu or may be other device features).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check the performance of other devices on your same WiFi. Are you getting the intended speed on it? Might be an internet issue at its core.

Secondly, there might be other WiFi from your neighbors that "overlap" with your WiFi and causing the issue. Use an app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en) and see which networks are the same channel.

Depending on how overlap, just change the WiFi channel in your router and see if it does the trick or not.